# multiple view (master-child) with ui-router-ng2 and component refresh

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router-ng2 in a multi ui-view configuration, with a master list component and a child details component.

`let state = { 
  name: 'hello', 
  url: '/',

  views: {
    'dashboard': {
      component: DashboardComponent
    },
    'detail': {
      component: DetailComponent
    }
  },
  params: {
    "dashboard-selected": 0,
    "detail-selected": 0
  },
  ...
}`

https://plnkr.co/edit/OKCOrdrlm8edDNEUXzDw?p=preview

This was a pretty fun exercise. See this plunker.

When the Dashboard component (master view) loads - it fetch a list of data. I simulate this with setTimeout(...,2000). And then it populates a list.

When different items are selected in the list, I put the ID into the dashboard-selected ui-param.
(try clicking around the links on the master view)

This is sent to the DetailComponent (child view) below.

The child view has several items as well, as I select them, I store the ID into the detail-selected ui-param. (try clicking around the links on the child view)

All seems good.

The problem is the data fetching on the master view. See, I don't want the object to refresh. But UI Router seems to be recreating that component everytime I select something in the child component, even if the dashboard-selected property doesn't change.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or whether conceptually I've gone off the wrong path somewhere.  So looking for feedback to discuss 'why the master component is refreshing and how to tell it to stop'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@christopherthielen answered this on the ui-router issue list and modified the plunker.  I think this is a great example of how master-detail works.  So I'm leaving this here for others to read.  I learn a lot about routing.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3351#issuecomment-282569117